# Passing a string inside viewDidAppear in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I want to pass a string inside a `viewDidAppear` but it takes only BOOL value. But i need to use that `viewDidAppear` for different `viewcontrollers` and in every view controller i want to use different string.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Google Analytics"];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}
```

Here in value we want to pass a string from different `viewControllers`. Please help !

Comment: which string you want to replace

Comment: You can't change the parameters for a cocoa API. The string variable must be accessible from ViewDidAppear, but it can't be passed to it.

Comment: value:@"Google Analytics" this should be different according to the different viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to send the name of the viewController in google analytics?

If it's correct, you change the `value` Be the traker

`[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"change here"]`

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by the use of subclass.

1. Create a subclass of type `UIViewController` like

**`SuperViewController.h`**

```
@interface SuperController : UIViewController
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *screenValue;
@end
```

**`SuperViewController.m`**

```
@implementation SuperViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:screenValue];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}

@end
```

2. Now use `SuperViewController` as subclass of all the ViewControllers you want to use the code in viewDidAppear like

**`YOURViewController.h`**

```
@interface YOURViewController : SuperViewController

@end
```

**`YOURViewController.m`**

```
@implementation YOURViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   self.screenValue=@"YOURSCREENVALUE";
}
@end
```

Define the `screenValue` value in `viewDidLoad` of each ViewController you assigned SuperViewController as subclass, it will automatically call viewDidAppear with specific screenName.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is one problem with this, because of single inheritance on Obj-C, you cannot use this method when you inherit from `UITableViewController`, `UICollectionViewController` etc.

Comment: There is another solution to not use `UITableViewController` or, `UICollectionViewController` use only `UIViewController` and embed `UITableView` or, `UICollectionView` inside?

Comment: You are right, though you loose some things - auto scrolling to focused textfields, static cells in storyboard, etc. Also, the problem gets worse if you want to use a custom library (from a cocoapod for instance) and it also requires you to inherit from their custom view controller.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to subclassing would be to use Objective-C categories. A category lets you add a method to a class (including classes from SDK).

So you could have something like this :

in `UIViewController+Tracking.h`

```
@interface UIViewController (Tracking)

- (void)track:(NSString *)trackingValue;

@end
```

and in `UIViewController+Tracking.m`

```
@implementation UIViewController (Tracking)

- (void)track:(NSString *)value {
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:trackingValue];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}

@end
```

After this, all instances and subclasses of `UIViewController` (including, for example, `UITableViewController` and its subclasses) will have this method available. And then you can use it like this :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self track:@"value you want to track"];
}
```

Comment: what if i want this for three or four classes, should i have to create a separate categories for them ?

Comment: If they all inherit from `UIViewController` then no. You can read more about categories [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). If, on the other hand, they don't share a common parent class then I'd suggest creating a singleton class to manage your tracking.